# Emoji on UILabel with vibrancy not readable

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uivisualeffectview, uivibrancyeffect

I've set up a simple `UIVisualEffectView` with `UILabel` inside the vibrancy content view. The vibrancy does work for the regular text, but it makes the Emoji unreadable.

Sample:

[image]

**Any Idea on how to fix this?**